# Move /boot to ESP (currently /boot/efi)

Tags: arch-linux, boot, grub2, uefi, boot-loader

I currently have my ESP partition at `/boot/efi` (actually, it's not even mounted there, no entry in `/etc/fstab` at all; I installed my system years ago and can't remember why it's setup that way but it's worked OK til now), and would like to have it at `/boot` instead. I'm currently using GRUB 2 as my boot loader but I don't really know how it works (again, I installed it years ago and never had to touch it since then). And this is Arch Linux.

**What would I have to do to make this happen?**

Copy everything from `/boot` to the ESP then add an entry to `/etc/fstab` to mount the ESP as `/boot`, but I suspect there might be paths to change in some config files now that EFI would be at `/boot/EFI` rather than `/boot/efi/EFI`.

Content of `/boot` currently:

- grub/
- initramfs-linux.img
- initramfs-linx-fallback.img
- intel-ucode.img
- vmlinuz-linux

Content of the ESP:

- EFI

  - arch

    - grubx64.efi
    - fwupdx64.efi
    - fw/
  - Dell/Bios/Recovery/

**Context:** I want to move to full disk encryption (using LVM on LUKS 2; currently, I have no encryption at all, neither `/` nor `/home`), and for that I need to have the kernel and initramfs on an unencrypted partition for GRUB to load (correct me if I'm wrong). I thought the easiest would be to simply have it on the ESP and thus make the ESP `/boot` rather than `/boot/efi`.

Suggestions for alternatives are welcome (please provide pros and cons).

Comment: You may have to reinstall Grub since the boot loader will have to open a FAT partition and no more an ext2. The `--efi-directory` option can specify the `/boot` directory as an EFI partition. 
I have not try such a configuration but I guess it should work.  Normally, `grub-install` determines the needed modules (here fat.mo) and make an EFI loader abled to open your the boot partition.

Comment: You probably have a BIOS/MBR configuration which does not use ESP. To see details: Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair  LVM is logical volumes and is totally contained in one physical partition. With Ubuntu newest grub2 can boot without a /boot partition outside LVM, but ESP still must be in a FAT32 partition not in LVM. LVM install to Arch
https://gist.github.com/mattiaslundberg/8620837 & 
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2370388

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR:**

1. copy everything from `/boot` to the ESP
2. mount the ESP to `/boot`
3. regenerate the `/boot/grub/grub.conf` through `grub-mkconfig`
4. run `grub-install` (mostly to update the EFI Boot)
5. reboot to the new boot
6. cleanup the old boot (`/boot`, `EFI/arch`, `efibootmgr`)

---

What I ended up doing, with success:

1. mount ESP to… anywhere (I used `/boot/efi`)
2. copy everything (particularly the initramfs, microcode, kernel, and `grub/` folder, though that last one might have not been necessary) from `/boot` to the ESP
3. unmount the ESP, and remount it to `/boot`
4. run `grub-mkconfig` to generate a new `/boot/grub/grub.conf`

At that point, I wanted to check that all would be running OK, so I:

5. unmounted the ESP and remounted it to `/boot/efi`
6. diffed the `/boot/grub/grub.conf` and `/boot/efi/grub/grub.conf`
7. copied `menuentry` blocks from one to the other so I could (hopefully) boot both options
8. rebooted and tried the new option to boot from the ESP: it worked (meaning, IIUC, that the files copied to the ESP were OK to boot the system)

I then jumped the gap and made the switch:

9. mount the ESP to `/boot`
10. edit the `/etc/fstab` to mount it on boot (I actually used `genfstab` to generate the appropriate fstab line)
11. run `grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/boot --bootloader-id=GRUB` (previous one was named `arch`, so no conflict)
12. reboot (note that I have a menuentry from my old grub.conf to, hopefully, boot on the old "system" just in case)

And finally, do some cleanup:

13. unmount ESP and remove everything from the *old* `/boot` (as ESP is mounted here anyway, shadowing those files)
14. remove the menuentry I added to my grub.conf
15. remove the old GRUB entry in EFI using `efibootmgr`
16. remove the old GRUB entry from the ESP (`/boot/EFI/arch/`)